# Is there a less code dense way to initialise an array with a non default constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, stdarray

I have an array of 4 objects, each of these objects are initialised with a non default constructor however the same variables are used for all 4 with no changes required. This code works, however I would like to know if there is a less code dense way of initialising each object as each of the array elements are just being initialised with the same values?

```
Class1.h:
std::array<Arrow, 4> skillArrow

Class1.cpp:
Class1::Class1() : skillArrow{ Arrow("gfx/leftArrow.png", mouse, input), Arrow("gfx/leftArrow.png", mouse, input), Arrow("gfx/leftArrow.png", mouse, input), Arrow("gfx/leftArrow.png", mouse, input)
{
}
```

```
Arrow.h:
Arrow(const char* filePath, Sprite *mouseSprite, Input *input);
```

Comment: Write a `makeDefaultArrow()` function that manufactures and returns the right `Arrow` instance; call it four times in the initializer.

Comment: Suppose the 4 were 4000; is there a way that avoids writing the same thing 4000 times?

Comment: Is it important that the `Arrow` constructor be called four times?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a delegating constructor like this:

```
struct Class1 {
 private:
  std::array<Arrow, 4> skillArrow;

  Class1(Arrow const & arrow) : skillArrow{arrow, arrow, arrow, arrow} {}

 public:
  Class1();
};

Class1::Class1() : Class1(Arrow("gfx/leftArrow.png", mouse, input)) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [std::array<T,N>::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill) in the constructor.

```
Class1::Class1() {
    skillArrow.fill({"gfx/leftArrow.png", mouse, input});
}
```

If, as [Nate Eldredge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634919/nate-eldredge) pointed out, is important to call the `Arrow` constructor four times, a normal loop would do the trick.

```
Class1::Class1() {
    for ( auto & s : skillArrow )
        s = Arrow("gfx/leftArrow.png", mouse, input);
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, but it means the `Arrow` constructor is only called once.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see. Those pointers are a lurking disaster.

Comment: The second solution still has slightly different behavior than the original: four Arrow objects are default-constructed and then overwritten with `operator=`.  This may be unimportant in the application at hand, but it'd still be interesting to find a solution where the behavior is exactly the same.